# Live Connect API - Create Sub-Folders

Tags: windows-phone-7, onedrive

I'm trying to create a sub folder using the Live Connect API for the Windows Phone 7.

I have successfully created a folder, but I would like to create a sub folder as well.  I have been looking here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826550.aspx but I have not been able to find a way to create a sub folder.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: A subfolder is a folder so why do you not create? :s

Comment: I can create a folder but what I want to do is create a folder under that, for example: (Folder_A/Folder_A1)  I can't seem to find an example of how to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of calling 

`client.PostAsync("me/skydrive", folderData);`

call something like this:

`client.PostAsync(folderId, folderData);`

You can obtain folder ID by calling list files/directories on skydrive.

Hope it helps